# How to add an iOS8 code snippet to an Adobe Air iOS app.xml?

Tags: ios, iphone, xml, air

I'm using Adobe Air to build an iOS 8 iPhone app and I would like to hide the status bar of iOS. I found this snippet that should do the trick:

```
<key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
<true/>
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
```

How to add it to the app.xml of my app?
I tried the following but received an *Unexpected element* error message:

```
<iPhone>
<InfoAdditions><![CDATA[
<key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
<true/>
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>       
]]></InfoAdditions>
</iPhone>
```

Comment: I think <fullscreen>true</fullscreen> is what you need - in the  <initialWindow> node of the xml.  It's in the publish settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f7e64a7f12cd2dd1867-8000.html%23WS901d38e593cd1bac6c9d409a12e26b451be-8000) you can not define that property in the XML

> AIR sets several entries in the generated Info.plist file to ensure
>   that application and runtime features work correctly. You cannot
>   define the following settings:
>
> CFBundleDisplayName
>
> CFBundleExecutable
>
> CFBundleIconFiles
>
> CFBundleIdentifier
>
> CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion
>
> CFBundlePackageType
>
> CFBundleResourceSpecification
>
> CFBundleShortVersionString
>
> CFBundleSupportedPlatforms
>
> CFBundleVersion
>
> CTAutoOrients
>
> CTInitialWindowTitle
>
> CTInitialWindowVisible
>
> CTIosSdkVersion
>
> CTMaxSWFMajorVersion
>
> DTPlatformName
>
> DTSDKName
>
> MinimumOSVersion (reserved till 3.2)
>
> NSMainNibFile
>
> UIInterfaceOrientation
>
> UIStatusBarHidden
>
> UISupportedInterfaceOrientations
>
> Note: You can define the MinimumOSVersion. The MinimumOSVersion
>   definition is honoured in Air 3.3 and later.

However, you can set the status bar style in initialWindow node like this

```
<fullScreen>true</fullScreen>
<systemChrome>none</systemChrome>
```

The first line will remove status on splash, the second during runtime